# Add existing hosts to hostgroups in Nagios

Tags: windows, nagios, automation

How can I add existing Hosts to HostGroups in Nagios XI, automatically? For example, I have an existing 100+ Windows servers that I want to add to a hostgroup called "Windows".

Answer (score 1):

here is an existing article on server fault, but it refers to nagios core. It inserts hosts automatically using REGEX, as long as  your windows servers have a common naming convention it could work.

[Nagios Multiple servers config files](https://serverfault.com/questions/376785/nagios-multiple-servers-config-files)